# WordPress - Merging two complex queries into one

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two fairly complex WordPress queries that I need to combine into a single query.

In my first query, I am getting Wordpress Posts by the date they are published. Each day of posts is contained inside a container, with the date showed above the posts as a title. It also only hides any posts that are in the past. Only posts from today or the future are shown.

In my second query, I am getting WordPress Posts from a Custom Taxonomy. For each term in the taxonomy, posts are displayed inside a container utilizing the slug of that term as a class, and displaying the name of the term as the title.

**What I need to accomplish and what I need help with, is as follows.**

I need the first query exactly as it is now, however, in the first query, where it says "// Need code here to display posts by taxonomy term //", I need to integrate the second query so that where posts are being output for that day, its also listing the posts by the term like in the second query.

Both queries function perfectly on their own, but I am having trouble with implementing a single query that utilizes the functionality from both queries to do what I need to do.

Here are my two queries:

**1st Query:**

```
<?php 
// First we get yesterdays date
$year = date("Y"); $month = date("m"); $yesterday = date("d", strtotime("-1 day"));
// Then we construct a query to get items from the calendar, either published or scheduled for a future date so that they appear on the calendar. We use date query to hide events that have already passed by querying after the date we got before. We use yesterdays date to ensure that TODAYS post are still obtained
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'calendar',
    'post_status' => 'publish,future',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'date_query' => array(
        array('after' => array(
                'year'  => $year,
                'month' => $month,
                'day'   => $yesterday
            )
        )
     )
 )); 
// This is a special loop that gets posts by day and encases each days worth of posts in a container and shows the date of those posts. jQuery will be applied to this
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    echo '<div class="day-posts">';
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<div class="day">';
        the_date('l jS F Y', '<div class="title"><div>', '</div>'); //Formats date, before echo, after echo
        echo '<div class="posts clearfix">';
        echo '<div class="post">';
        the_title('<div class="title">', '</div>');
        echo '<div class="content">';
        // Need custom code here to display posts by taxonomy //
        the_content();
        echo '</div></div></div></div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}?>
```

**2nd Query:**

```
<?php
$post_type = array('calendar');
$tax = 'event-category';
$tax_terms = get_terms($tax, array('orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'ASC'));
if ($tax_terms) {
    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            "$tax" => $tax_term->slug,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => - 1,
            'caller_get_posts' => 1
            ); // END $args
        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
            echo '<div class="' . $tax_term->slug . '">';
            echo '<div class="title">' . $tax_term->name . '</div>;
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
?>

<?php the_title();?>
<?php the_content();?>

<?php endwhile; echo '</div>'; } wp_reset_query(); }  } ?>
```

I hope I have done a good job of explaining what I am trying to do. If I have not, or there are questions, please ask and I'll answer as quick as I can.

Comment: You have two different `order`/`orderby` values in your queries. Wordpress doesn't support array of order values so this can't be combine. In this case you need custom SQL query.

Comment: The order value in the second query isn't important. It can be discarded.

Comment: could you list out the parameters for the posts you want? i see in the 2nd query you are trying to organize by taxonomy with headins?

Comment: As explained above, I need the posts to be returned by day, as in the first query, with each day of posts in its own container. Within the container for each day of posts, each taxonomy term should be looped through and have the title for the tax-term displayed and any posts categorized in that tax-term.

Comment: Here is a very crude flowchart which might help clarify things: http://imgur.com/sEhHae3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here you go (I dont have posts setup like your query so i didn't test it but i believe this what you are looking for):

```
// Setup the basic structure:
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'calendar',
    'post_status' => 'publish,future',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => array(
                'year'  => $year,
                'month' => $month,
                'day'   => $yesterday
            )
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'caller_get_posts' => 1
);

// For dynamic taxonomy term create a bootstrap tax_query

$tax = 'event-category';
$tax_terms = get_terms($tax, array('orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'ASC'));
if ($tax_terms) {

    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $tax,
            'field' => 'slug',
        )
    );

    // Append the slugs to the tax_query terms
    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
        $args['tax_query'][0]['terms'][] = $tax_term->slug;
    }
}

// Your One and only QUERY
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

For `$tax_term->slug` and `$tax_term->name` you could use [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) within the query loop like:

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, $tax);
$terms = array_slice($terms, 0);
$term = $terms[0];

echo $term->slug;
echo $term->name;
```

## EDITED

See code comments for explanation/clarification

```
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    $_tax = false;
    $same_date = array(); // collection of same dates
    $same_date_bool = true; // determine previous post date exist

    echo '<div class="day-posts">';
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        $date = get_the_date('l jS F Y');

        $same_date_bool = true;

        // Checking if post is displayed from the current date
        // then this post should be appended inside to previous
        // opened div.day tag
        if (!empty($same_date) && in_array($date, $same_date)) {
            $same_date_bool = false;
        }

        // Collecting all dates
        $same_date[] = $date;

        // If post is not in same date
        // create new div element

        if ($same_date_bool) {
            echo '<div class="day">
                <div class="title">';
            echo $date;
            echo '</div>';
        }

        // If post is not in same date
        // create new div element

        if ($same_date_bool) {
            echo '<div class="posts clearfix">';
        }

        echo '<div class="post">';
        the_title('<div class="title">', '</div>');
        echo '<div class="content">';

        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, $tax);
        // Note: I'm assuming your post will
        // always have single term
        $terms = array_slice($terms, 0);
        $term = $terms[0];

        if ($term) {
            $_tax = true;
            echo '<div class="' . $term->slug . '">';
            echo '<div class="title">' . $term->name . '</div>';
        }

        the_content();

        if ($_tax) {
            echo '</div>';
        }

        echo '</div></div>';

        // If post is in same date
        // append closing div element for previous "div.day" element
        if (!$same_date_bool) {
            echo '</div></div>';
        }
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Hope this helps now. Also I have replaced the `caller_get_posts` with `ignore_sticky_posts` because `caller_get_posts` has been deprecated since v3.1

Comment: Could you include an example of how I would output the posts here? The structure of your code looks like it would do what I need, however, I am unsure how to output the posts in the way that I need, with this code.

Comment: @ZachNicodemous For proper result, if possible please export your post data and have a link it in your question so we can test it our self.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. I am testing the code now on the site and I am getting data output, however, it is not quite right. I used the code as provided first, and have now added some extra divs in there to show what should be where. First, I have taken a screenshot of the output code and added some annotations to highlight the issues. This can be seen here: http://i.imgur.com/PDScdLk.png - -  Second, here is the code as it is currently used in my page, with the new added divs and such: http://pastebin.com/NiX9h1Gt - have tried to correct myself, but no luck. I am a bit out of my depth.

Comment: Been trying to solve this myself but I am just breaking it more and more and more >_<

Comment: @ZachNicodemous You should provide the sample data if you need golden code. Screenshot won't help much.

Comment: Here is an export of the sample data. It just has 6 sample entries, however, I do not know if you'll be able to import it without setting up the custom post type and custom taxonomy. https://mega.co.nz/#!R0RV0JSZ!TUwD5pFiWdT0z1np1y6ImdyF7nDpSI2Vqi4LASCbjYY

Comment: Were you able to download the sample data?

Comment: This code is improved & closer to what it needs to be, but there are still glitches: 1) If there are two or more posts on the same day that use the same tax-term, eg "Youth", there should only be one instance of the title "Youth", with all posts under it that use that term. 2) There seems to be an issue with divs too. When I do a straight copy/paste of this code into a blank page and check the output, its clear there is a structure issue: http://i.imgur.com/yY2fmBm.png Am going to try and resolve both issues myself and IF I make any progress will post right away.